# Ractive teardown but preserve dom

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, ractivejs

Is there a way in Ractive to destroy the instance (unrender event listeners, etc) but not remove the DOM changes that it made?

I'm building a one page app and the goal is that each view is its own instance of ractive. However, in some cases there is persistent data and I want to avoid a 'pop in' effect. By preserving what's in the DOM, the next ractive instance can load on page change and do its diff, removing anything that changed but preserve the things that didn't.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One question though: Why would you want to do this? I believe your real problem is not about Ractive being able (or not able) to do this, but something else entirely.

Comment: Lets say I'm loading a page about a sports team. Inside this page, there are several "tabs" for each piece of information, but through them all the team name in the top stays the same. Each tab is its own ractive instance (only 1 per page). as you switch tabs, it'll destroy the previous view with information, and rebuild with the new template. However, the header information persists through these views. If i was downloading this team information from say an API and NOT caching them, I would run into a situation where the view gets destroyed, and once it loads there is a "pop in" effect.

Comment: Why not move out the header data separate from the tab data, and render the header in a separate component? That way, changing just the tab data won't affect (thus won't re-render) the header component? Additionally, when Ractive sees that the data didn't change, even after setting identical data (ie. setting 2 when the value is already 2), it won't re-render.

Comment: Why don't you store that data in localstorage so when the code runs you check to see if it is in localstorage. If not, you ask them for the info, if it is, you do not ask. OR do not destroy the data source that has the info in it that you are binding to the instance of Ractive.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I went with your solution and it seems to have fixed all the issues I was having. Thanks so much!